# PHPWord in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpword

I want to use PHPWord on laravel 5 but I cannot find any packages for it. So I decided to add it manually but still I do not have success.

I have tried this tutorials and github files:

- https://github.com/maveius/Laravel-Word
- http://laravel.io/forum/05-26-2014-how-can-i-export-to-word

Also some of it was gone when I just read it yesterday.

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PHPWord is on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpword), so installing it on Laravel is as easy as:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

or adding this to your composer.json then running `composer install`:

```
"require": {
   "phpoffice/phpword": "dev-master"
}
```

Once installed, you can use it in your code like this (taken from the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#getting-started)):

```
// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */

 // Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText(
    htmlspecialchars(
        '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
            . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
            . '(Albert Einstein)'
    )
);

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.html');
```

Comment: Does this PHPWord create doc, docx files ? ?

Comment: Yes it creates doc and docx files.

Comment: dose this will help to preview the word file in a browser.