# PHPWord - Class ''PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord' not found

Tags: php, laravel

Getting an error Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord' not found
My composer.json
"php": ">=7.0.0",
        "abrigham/laravel-email-exceptions": "^1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4",
        "ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package": "^3.5",
        "karlomikus/theme": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "leafo/scssphp": "^0.7.7",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "nicolaslopezj/searchable": "1.*",
        "niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf": "^3.1",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^0.17.0",
        "shivella/laravel-bitly": "^1.0",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^2.0",
        "sofa/laravel-global-scope": "^0.2.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.0",
        "zendframework/zend-escaper": "^2.6",
        "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "^3.2"

Comment: execute this command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Please format your code. Also please specify the framework you are working on and other details.

Comment: Please share more details. Have you checked whether that class is properly stored? Have you checked whether the autoloader was included?

Answer (score -1):

maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627457/1873569) can help you

```
// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */

 // Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText(
    htmlspecialchars(
        '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
            . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
            . '(Albert Einstein)'
    )
);

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.html');


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627457/1873569
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How does all that code, and especially that quote from Einstein, solve the autoloader problem given in the question?