# Upload Bulk question answers from MS Word file in php

Tags: php, laravel

How we can read and parse bulk questions and answer from MS word DOC file in php. I have multiple question and answers having mathematical calculations and equations given below in the image:[image]

```
function read_file_docx($filename){

$striped_content = '';
$content = '';

if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

$zip = zip_open($filename);

if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

    if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

    $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
}

zip_close($zip);

$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
$striped_content = strip_tags($content);

return $striped_content;
```

}

```
$filename =$r->file;

$content = $this->read_file_docx($filename);
if($content !== false) {

    echo nl2br($content);
}
else {
    echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.';
}

exit;
```

How we can extract question and answer separately to upload in database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPWord in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627389/phpword-in-laravel-5)

Comment: This really depends on how the word file is structured. If you can get each line individually you can them split your lines into groups each group starting with a regex like e.g. `^Q\d+\.` so all lines between one that matches this regex and the next one that matches this regex are in the same group). Then within each group the question is everything until the line with `(a)` and with the same idea you can determine the correct answer and solution (if you want to store those as well). It is (as you can see) complicated and will require quite a bit of work to do that

Comment: If the question is not about how to read a word file, but rather how to parse the text you are successfully obtaining from it - please edit the question to focus on that specifically (in which case, the fact the text came from word is not particularly relevant).

Comment: Question is about to read and parse both. May be my method of reading is not correct so I need suggestion reading too. @AD7six